# Host CIFS files on NGINX under Windows

Tags: windows, nginx, smb, cifs

I have NGINX running on a Windows box. I'd really like it to host files which are stored on a neighboring box using CIFS, but I can't figure out how to handle it in the config.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    sendfile off;
    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /share {
        root //otherserver/share/files;
    }
}
```

When I try pulling a file from that location I get this:

```
2015/05/05 10:28:37 [error] 6600#13064: *12 CreateFile() "C:\Users\me\Desktop\nginx/\\otherserver/share/files/sample.mp4" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /share/sample.mp4 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Clearly NGINX is interpreting my command as a relative path.

**Is there a way to use a CIFS/SMB UNC path in nginx.conf?**

**If not, how can I host files stored on a CIFS share?**

Many thanks!

Comment: Mount it as a disk. But it's really strange idea

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Under Linux (and fstab) that would be pretty straight forward. 

As I'm in a Windows environment mounting a share as a disk is kind of an ugly solution to this problem. (Unless maybe I do it at the NTFS level...) 

I suppose I could script an exec into the nginx config which would map the path on demand... But I feel like there's got to be a way to do this within NGINX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

root "//ip-address/share/files";

And make sure the user/pass on this unc share is the same as the user/pass nginx.exe is using.

Comment: Alright! Double quotes save the day!

The only other problem that I had was that I was incorrectly using the "root" keyword, when I should have been using the "alias" keyword.

The new config is:

    location /share {
       alias "//otherserver/share/files"
    }

Thanks!

Comment: not working when serving windows file path...even tried convertin \ to /.Didn't work